# Why Odoo not insert this two columns?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm creating a custom module to extend fields in sale.order.line but Odoo (v8) doesn't create these two columns.

```
class sale_order_line_ext(osv.Model):
    _name = 'sale.order.line'
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    _columns = {
        'supplier_name': fields.char('Supplier name'),
        'supplier_ref': fields.char('Product reference'),
    }

sale_order_line_ext()
```

I have already created some columns in sale.order previously, but I don't see anything wrong here. What is my error?

Comment: First off: i don't know why both answers suggest to remove _name attribute, because that isn't necessary. And second: why don't you use new API? I guess you forgot to init the file or just didn't restart the server. No offense to that, it is just a usual mistake.

Comment: @CZoellner I have suggested to remove `_name`  because his  requirement is not add another model, he is adding fields to the same model. This is why `_name`  is not required there.

Comment: OK, it is not required but it is also not a mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your comment, error log says `supplier_name` doesn't exist in table  `sale.order.line'` , to check this go to settings -> Technical -> Database Structure -> Models and find `sale.order.line` then you will see all fields. If not try below code:

```
class sale_order_line_ext(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    _columns = {
    'supplier_name': fields.char('Supplier name'),
    'supplier_ref': fields.char('Product reference'),
     }

sale_order_line_ext()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have added these field in model `sale.order.line`, but you have not added them in the view. If you want to show these fields in sale order line then you will have to inherit the `tree view` `'Sales Order Lines'` and add these fields in the tree view.

```
<record id="pob_order_line_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">  
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Order Lines']/field[@name='order_line']/tree[@string='Sales Order Lines']/field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <field name= 'supplier_name'/>
            <field name= 'supplier_ref'/>
        </xpath>
    </field>        
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @VikashMishra . I have already created this view, but I didn't put it here. When I try to add these field in the view, Odoo returns an error:
`Detalles de error:
El campo supplier_name no existe

Error de contexto:
Vista sale.order.form.inherit
[view_id: 832, xml_id: sale_extensions.view_order_form_extension, model: sale.order, parent_id: 650]" while parsing /home/marcogonzalo/Dentaltix/ERP/bitnami-odoo/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/sale_extensions/views/sale_form_views.xml:4, near`

Comment: remove the `_name=sale.order.line` from your `.py` file and restart your odoo server and then upgrade your module